# HapiJs File Upload : 500 Internal Server Error while uploading large files, Reply never reaches back to the ccaller

Tags: node.js, hapi.js, iisnode

**We are using IISNODE to host our node application written using "hapi": "^16.5.2", the Route is pasted below**

```
{ 
    method: 'POST',
    path: '/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/Upload/',
    config: {
        auth: { strategies: ['simple'] },
        handler: uploadHandler.Upload,
        plugins: {
            'hapi-swagger': {
                responses: fileHTTPStatus,
                payloadType: 'form'
            },
            disinfect: {
                disinfectQuery: false,
                disinfectParams: false,
                disinfectPayload: false
            },
            policies: ['MethodAudit']
        },
        tags: ['api'],
        validate: {
            payload: {
                file: Joi.any().meta({ swaggerType: 'file' }).required().description('file')
            }
        },
        payload: {
            maxBytes: 209715200,
            parse: true,
            allow: 'multipart/form-data',
            output: 'stream'
        },
        cors: {
            origin: ['*'],
            additionalHeaders: ['cache-control', 'x-requested-with', 'accept', 'authorization', 'content-type', 'if-none-match', 'origin', 'Accept-language']
        }
    }
}
```

**uploadHandler.Upload Method looks like this:**

```
function Upload (request, reply) {
if (request.payload) {
    var data = request.payload;

    if (data.file) {

        var originalName = data.file.hapi.filename;

        var path = rootDocPath + originalName; //rootDocPath is our common location

        var file = fs.createWriteStream(path);

        file.on('error', function (err) {
            console.error(err)
        });

        data.file.pipe(file);

        file.on('end', function() {
            console.log('file ended');
        });

        file.on('finish', function() {
            console.log('file finished');
        });

        data.file.on('end', function(err) {
            console.log('data.file ended');
        });

        file.on('close', function(err) {
            reply('Uploaded');
        });

    } else {
        reply('no file')
    }
} else {
    reply('no payload')
}
```

}

The response which we get is **IIS 8.5 Detailed Error - 500.1013 - Internal Server Error**

- While debugging we could see that reply("Uploaded") is being executed but the response is never received by the caller.
- This behaviour is only exhibited with larger files (more than 1.9
  MB), for smaller files it works 100%

Comment: Is there any file upload limit on your IISNODE installation. maybe first you should check that end..

Comment: We checked the system.webServer/serverRuntime settings and uploadReadAheadSize is more than 200MB. If we run the application without IISNODE, we see similar behavior, 500 Internal Server Error is replaced by No Content

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is something going on in your stream pipe.

Here is my **dump** uploader which uses promises I never had a single problem with it. Maybe you can compare with your process.

```
const fileUploader = function (file, targetPath) {
    if (!file) throw new Error('no file');
    const fileStream = fs.createWriteStream(targetPath);

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        file.on('error', function (err) {
            reject(err);
        });

        file.pipe(fileStream);

        file.on('end', function (err) {
            resolve({
                fieldname: file.hapi.name,
                originalname: file.hapi.filename,
                mimetype: file.hapi.headers['content-type'],
                targetPath,
                size: fs.statSync(targetPath).size,
            });
        })
    })
};

// usage
const filePath = await helpers.fileUploader(request.payload.data, targetPath);
```

Comment: I tried using your code and the code creates the Physical File successfully, Even with my code the file gets creates successfully, it's just the reply part which does not work at all. The caller of the endpoint never gets the response back.

Comment: Maybe try to put your reply file.on('end') call. I don't have any other valid point about your code. It looks clean.

Answer (score 0):

The fix that worked for me was to set the request payload to null before sending a response back to the caller. Seems like if the request payload size is too large the service is unable to respond. Please see the fix below (look for the comment **This is the FIX**):

```
function Upload (request, reply) {
 if (request.payload) {
    var data = request.payload;

    if (data.file) {

        var originalName = data.file.hapi.filename;

        var path = rootDocPath + originalName; //rootDocPath is our common location

        var file = fs.createWriteStream(path);

        file.on('error', function (err) {
            console.error(err)
        });

        data.file.pipe(file);

        file.on('end', function() {
            console.log('file ended');
        });

        file.on('finish', function() {
            console.log('file finished');
        });

        data.file.on('end', function(err) {
            console.log('data.file ended');
        });

        file.on('close', function(err) {
            request.payload.file = null; /*This is the FIX*/
            reply('Uploaded');
        });

    } else {
        reply('no file')
    }
 } else {
     reply('no payload')
 }
}
```